# Cambiar caracteres dentro de una cadena

Tags: c#, comparaciones

Sé invertir dos números de un array con el `array.reverse` pero, en este caso, tengo declarado un `String` que entras por el método de entrada y que este se trasforma en array con el método `Split` separado por `','`.

En la cadena pueden existir estas combinaciones: `1,12,2,23,3,34,4,14`.

Lo que necesito es que si entras por teclado `21` te lo invierta a `12`, al igual que con `32`, que se invierta a `23` etc.

Mi duda es la siguiente a ver si se explicarme bien. Yo he guardado en el array numeros entre 1 el y el 4 combinados ejemplo: 12,32,41,24). Dejando aparte que hay combinaciones que no pueden existir por los requisitos de mi ejercicio necesito mirar dentro de las posiciones del array si el numero esta ordenado de menor a mayor y si no lo esta cambiarlo.
Actualmente mi programa no me resuelve este problema simplemente me pone izquierda derecha arriba abajo etc cuando le inserto un numero pero tiene que estar bien ordenado(de menor a mayor), si no lo ordeno me muestra el numero sin mas, no el enum al que hace referencia. Creo que tendría primero que mirar el indice [i] del array y comprar el numero que hay dentro de este pero al ser un numero de dos dígitos no se comprar el primer carácter con el segundo.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace Ejercicio3
  {
      class Program
      {
          enum direcion { arriba = 1, abajo = 3, derecha = 2, izquieda = 4, 
  abajoDerecha=23, abajoIzquierda=34,arribaDerecha=12,arribaIzquieda=14, 
  prohibido };
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              string num = "";
              Console.WriteLine("Escribe la direcion que desees tomar");
              num = Console.ReadLine();
              string[] array = num.Split(',');

              for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
              {
                  if (array[i].Length==2)
                 {
                  var a=int.Parse(array[i].Substring(0, 1));
                var b=int.Parse(array[i].Substring(1,2));
                {
                    if (a < b)
                    {
                        array[i].Reverse;
                    }

                }
                  }
                  Console.WriteLine("{0}", (direcion)int.Parse(array[i]));
              }     

          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84551/discussion-on-question-by-winnie-cambiar-caracteres-dentro-de-una-cadena).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El metodo array.reverse, segun su [definición](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=netframework-4.7.2) lo que hace es invertir el orden de determinados elementos de un array, entre ellos.

Lo que vos queres, no es eso.

Tu array, tiene numeros en cada posicion, y lo que vos queres es transformar numeros como si fueran posicionales, en numeros ordenados.

O sea que si tenes el numero 41, lo que vos queres es que aparezca el 14...

Entonces, tenes todo resulto, ya como lo hiciste, haciendo solo un pequeño cambio...

Veamos, si `a` es < `b`, entonces estaria bien el número... si es al reves, deberiamos cambiar el numero..

Yo no los trabajaria como numeros, ya que como string, es igual de facil, y despues va a ser mas facil volver a concatenarlos.

```
string a = array[i].Substring(0, 1);
string b = array[i].Substring(1, 1);
if (a.CompareTo(b) > 0)
{
    array[i] = b + a;
}
```

Prueba con eso, seguro te va a simplicar las cosas.

Comment: si pongo b+a me va a sumar los dos valores no me va a poner el b seguido del a.

Comment: no, porque ahora son strings :p @winnie

Comment: El programa me dice que no puedo operar con strings en el caso de if (a>b).

Comment: @winnie proba usar `char` en la condición, en lugar de `if( a > b)` usa `if(a[0] > b[0])`

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal a y b son cadenas, para que querria hacer eso?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal si hago eso si me compila pero me salta error en cuanto pongo un una diagonal.

Comment: ok @winnie dame 5 min ya te lo arreglo

Comment: @gbianchi al querer comparar string con `>` `<` Visual Studio no lo permite, por eso, sabiendo que es sólo un caracter plantee esa idea

Comment: @winnie corregido.. proba con este codigo

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal listo ya lo arregle.. el substring estaba mal tambien

Comment: @gbianchi eres un crack gracias! puedes explicarme porque pones el compareTo?

Comment: Porque lo necesitas para comparar strings.